# Laravel Register Index not found and create error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, authentication

i'm using laravel auth for login, register, forget password, etc
and custom view using jquery not vue.js

i'm using Auth Routes() in routes and planning to custom routing to custom my need, everytime i register using my template and route it to route('register') in my view register page, it shows view index does not found how can i custom this view index to my desire view? i could find it in register controller,

here's my register page view

```
                                    <form action="{{ route('register') }}" method="POST">
                                        @csrf
                                        <div class="form-head">
                                            <a href="{{url('/')}}" class="logo"><img src="assets/images/logo.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="logo"></a>
                                        </div> 
                                        <h4 class="text-primary my-4">Sign Up !</h4>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name Here" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email here" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password here" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="re-password" placeholder="Re-Type Password" required>
                                        </div> -->
                                        <div class="form-row mb-3">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox text-left">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="terms">
                                                    <label class="custom-control-label font-14" for="terms">I Agree to Terms & Conditions of Orbiter</label>
                                                </div>                                
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                          
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block font-18">Register</button>
                                    </form>
```

and i also have issue after it shows view index error it doesn't call register function, i checked this in my db and nothing adds up

here's my controller though

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }


    protected function create(array $data)
    {


     $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);


        $role = Role::select('id')->where('name', 'user')->first();

        $user->roles()->attach($role);

        return $user;
    }
```

i also tried this but still shows the same error view index does not exist

```
use RegistersUsers;


    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('user-register');
    }
``
```

Comment: just override default `showRegistrationForm` from `RegistersUsers` trait

Answer (score 0):

`RegisterController` uses a trait called `RegistersUsers`, which has a method `showRegistrationForm()`. You can override this method in your `RegisterController` to return your custom view. For example:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('custom-view');
    }
}
```

Comment: hi there thanks for stopping by i already try this solution and try to place in in both under use registeruser and my create function both return the same error message view index does not found

Comment: could you me post the code for your showRegistrationForm()? and the file path of your view file?

Comment: sure i already update it in my question feel free to look sir :)

Comment: it says view not found so must be a name issue for the view. Could you tell me where your view is in the views folder? Like register view is in views/auth/register. What is your view's location?

Comment: sure it's located in views/user-register should i move the file to folder views/auth/user-register ?

Comment: try it. and then return it as view('auth.user-register')

Comment: To customize the register view content, I have edited the register view provided by laravel. Why dont you do the same instead of creating another view?

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to redirect the user to a custom view when the user has registered.

You just need to add this function inside register controller.

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect('url goes here')
}
```